# Group by data by key and return a new object containing the sum value of another key

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have data like that:

```
const data = [
  {name: 'alice', colors: ['red', 'blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'},
  {name: 'duke', colors: ['red', 'blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-12-12'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: ['blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-11'},
  {name: 'alice', colors: ['blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-10'},
  {name: 'carl', colors: ['blue'], count: 3, day: '2018-11-01'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: ['red'], count: 1, day: '2017-11-12'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: [], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-11'},
  {name: 'alice', colors: ['yellow'], count: 2, day: '2018-11-11'},
  {name: 'duke', colors: ['red', 'yellow'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'},
];
```

Now I want to group by data by day and get the sum of key count so obtain an array of objects like that:

```
const newData = [
  {day: '2018-11-12', countSum: 5}, // sum of {name: 'alice', colors: ['red', 'blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'}, {name: 'alice', colors: [blue'], count: 2, day: '2018-11-12'}, {name: 'bob', colors: [], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'}, {name: 'duke', colors: ['red', 'yellow'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'}
  {day: '2018-12-12', countSum: 1},
  {day: '2018-11-11', countSum: 2}, // sum of {name: 'bob', colors: [blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-11'}, {name: 'bob', colors: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-11'}
  {day: '2018-11-10', countSum: 1},
  {day: '2018-11-01', countSum: 3},
  {day: '2017-11-12', countSum: 1},
]
```

I tried to use `groupBy` of Lodash to group data by day but I can't to count the sum of count key.
I need help.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to "Reduce" solution by charlietfl, you can use for..of too.

```js
const data = [
  {name: 'alice', colors: ['red', 'blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'},
  {name: 'duke', colors: ['red', 'blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-12-12'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: ['blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-11'},
  {name: 'alice', colors: ['blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-10'},
  {name: 'carl', colors: ['blue'], count: 3, day: '2018-11-01'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: ['red'], count: 1, day: '2017-11-12'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: [], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-11'},
  {name: 'alice', colors: ['yellow'], count: 2, day: '2018-11-11'},
  {name: 'duke', colors: ['red', 'yellow'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'},
];

let result = {}

for(let d of data) {
  result[d.day] = result[d.day] || { day: d.day, countSum: 0}
  result[d.day].countSum += d['count']
}

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array#reduce()` to create an object with the common property value (day) as keys then use `Object.values()` to return expected array

```js
const counts = data.reduce((a, {day, count}) => {
   a[day] = a[day] || {day, countSum:0}
   a[day].countSum += count
   return a
},{})

const res = Object.values(counts)

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
  {name: 'alice', colors: ['red', 'blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'},
  {name: 'alice', colors: ['blue'], count: 2, day: '2018-11-12'},
  {name: 'duke', colors: ['red', 'blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-12-12'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: ['blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-11'},
  {name: 'alice', colors: ['blue'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-10'},
  {name: 'carl', colors: ['blue'], count: 3, day: '2018-11-01'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: ['red'], count: 1, day: '2017-11-12'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: [], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'},
  {name: 'bob', colors: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-11'},
  {name: 'alice', colors: ['yellow'], count: 2, day: '2018-11-11'},
  {name: 'duke', colors: ['red', 'yellow'], count: 1, day: '2018-11-12'},
]
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [lodash](https://lodash.com/) approach. First **groupBy** `day` and then **map** each result of that group, and perform **sumBy** on each groups by `count`, That's it

```js
var data = [{"name":"alice","colors":["red","blue"],"count":1,"day":"2018-11-12"},{"name":"duke","colors":["red","blue"],"count":1,"day":"2018-12-12"},{"name":"bob","colors":["blue"],"count":1,"day":"2018-11-11"},{"name":"alice","colors":["blue"],"count":1,"day":"2018-11-10"},{"name":"carl","colors":["blue"],"count":3,"day":"2018-11-01"},{"name":"bob","colors":["red"],"count":1,"day":"2017-11-12"},{"name":"bob","colors":[],"count":1,"day":"2018-11-12"},{"name":"bob","colors":["red","blue","yellow"],"count":1,"day":"2018-11-11"},{"name":"alice","colors":["yellow"],"count":2,"day":"2018-11-11"},{"name":"duke","colors":["red","yellow"],"count":1,"day":"2018-11-12"}];

var res =_(data)
           .groupBy('day')
           .map((grp, day) => ({day, countSum: _.sumBy(grp, 'count')}))
           .value();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```